# not getting Microsoft Docs VB.NET examples anymore. They are all in C#

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

For example, for a line in my Visual Studio 2017 Pro .vb file which is:
Process.Start( my_process )

I double-click "Start" and press F1,  and then the Process.Start Method page opens, but all examples are only in C#.

Here's the URL it opens:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Diagnostics.Process.Start);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2

It used to be, it would show either C# or VB.

This started happening about a month or two ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click this button on the top right you can change the language the examples are in.

[image]

Cookies in your browser will make it remember your last choice next time you open a new page to the help.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/workflows/new-database

No VB choice. Sad really. VB isn't dead and needs to be included. Nothing you can do in C# I can't do in VB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VB.NET is not dead. As long as the VB.NET lovers like us continue to use it, it won't die.

I still code in VB.NET both for Classic Windows Forms and ASP.NET MVC web apps.

Yes, majority of the sample codes around are in C# but I could convert it to VB.NET with little effort.

I could understand C# but since I am so used to VB.NET, I am more productive on it and is much faster.

Even the simple "Try Catch", intellisence works perfect. Just type "Try" and intellisense would auto populate it. Try that with C#, nothing happens.

Just understand the C# code (not memorize), what does it do and we won't have trouble converting it to VB.NET.

You need basic C# basic Case Statement, If then Else, List, Arrays, etc.

There are also online converters from C# to VB.NET